# what is $\lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x-1}+x^2$, the problem is : $-\infty+1$

Tags: calculus

i am having a problem trying to find if the function is continuous in $0$,$1$,$-1$

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x-1}+x^2 , & \text{if }|x| < 1  \\[2ex]
\frac1{x^2+1}, & \text{if }|x| \ge 1
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is continuous in $0$, ok

But how about $1$?

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x-1}+x^2$

i am confused, for the reason that i get $-\infty+1$ and

can i say that $-\infty+1 = -\infty$?

thanks

Comment: Yes, but what about $x\to 1^+$?

Comment: yes you can say that because positive infinity is something which is greater than all positive real numbers and negative infinity is greater than all negative real number. So if i just add another number to this infinity we are going to get infinity

Comment: if i'm not wrong $x\to 1^+$ gives me 1/2, $-\infty$ != 1/2 so now i can say that $f$ isn't continuous on 1. thank you all !!!